# How to launch git diff in AppCode UI?

Tags: git, diff, appcode

I have a current commit and want to check the code difference with one of the previous tags.
I can run this in the console:

```
git diff my_tag
```

But I want to see it in the AppCode UI. I can make a new branch from my tag and then launch diff. But, I don't want to do it. I want to launch the diff with my tag without additional steps.

I did not find a context command in AppCode that will help me to do it. So, I think I need to launch it through console and pass it to AppCode.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Not complete diff as in Xcode but you could compare current changes with previous commit via `VCS->Local History->Show History`

Answer (score 1):

1. `VCS > Git > Branches > Checkout Tag or Revision`
2. Type in the name of the tag and click OK.
3. `VCS > Git > Compare with Branch... > master`

Comment: Yes, it will work. But not the way I want to. (i.e. I will need to switch on tag, check differences, then switch back on my branch)

Comment: You can use `Checkout Tag or Revision` again to switch back to the previous branch.

Comment: Better if I will create new branch from tag and check diff against it w/o switching revisions all the time. But not an option for me.
I want to keep things simple. 
Like I said, I can launch diff in console `git diff my_tag` and it works fine. I just want to see it inside AppCode UI. There should be the way how to pass diff output to AppCode.